# How to build jenkinsfile from a repo which triggered jenkins job when using multiple repositories in SCM in one jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple repositories which require a cd pipeline and all the repositories have their own jenkinsfile with same name. I have configured one jenkins pipeline for all the repositories by adding multiple repositories in "pipeline script from SCM" section.

When any of the repository is updated the pipeline triggers but it uses jenkinsfile of the first repository mentioned in the list of repos.

Is their anyway we can change this behaviour and make the Jenkins job run Jenkinsfile from a repository which triggered the build.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by shared library https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/
https://www.tutorialworks.com/jenkins-shared-library/

You can define various logic and functions to manage multiple repositories and their variables.
Also, try to make generic script which can behave based on the supplied parameters.